# [H]:MM:SS Format from Excel Cell to body of Outlook Email

Tags: excel, email, outlook, format

Ok So I'm stuck on this Excel VBA code. I have it automatically generating emials in outlook with information from the sheet already inputed. BUT When i try to move a Cell thats formatted as [h]:mm:ss it puts a decimal version of the number in the outlook email.

```
Sub Mail_test()

'Set variables/objects for code.
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim eto As String
    Dim ecc As String
    Dim esub As String
    Dim ebody As String
    Dim ebody1 As String
    Dim ebody2 As String
    Dim ebody3 As String
    Dim ebody4 As String
    Dim intbody As String

    Dim wkDay As String
    Dim otOff As String
    Dim intbody2 As String
    Dim intbody3 As String
    Dim ebody6 As String
    Dim intbody4 As String
    Dim intbody5 As String
    Dim ebody7 As String
    Dim Ebody10 As String
    Dim ebody11 As String
    Dim Ebody12 As String
Dim intbody12 As String
Dim intbody13 As String
Dim Ebody13 As String

    Dim ebody15  As String
    Dim ebody20 As String
    Dim Ebody21 As String
    Dim Ebody22 As String
    Dim Tempefile As String









'Sets application to update with code executions.
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With





'Conditional to determine if the code should continue.










mydate = E3

'Sets default body of the email.
Ebody12 = "Hello "
intbody12 = Sheets("Emails").Range("b3")
ebody15 = "," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
Ebody13 = "We are doing our Bi-Weekly Aux 2 Audit. " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
ebody11 = "This Escalation is for Agent: "
Ebody10 = Sheets("Emails").Range("AgentName").Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
ebody1 = "Your agent was over the allotted time for aux 2 for the two week period :"
ebody2 = "Agents are allotted 1.33% of their staffed time. " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
ebody3 = "Your agents staffed time was : "
intbody = Sheets("Emails").Range("stafftime") & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
ebody4 = "Your Agents Aux 2 percentage for the last two weeks was : "
intbody2 = Sheets("Emails").Range("auxper").Value
ebody5 = "????"
intbody3 = Sheets("Emails").Range("F3").Value
ebody6 = " Can we please have this coached?  " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
intbody4 = Sheets("Emails").Range("g3").Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
ebody7 = "Your agents Aux 2 time was :"
intbody5 = Sheets("Emails").Range("Auxhours").Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
intbody13 = Sheets("Emails").Range("I3").Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
ebody20 = "Thank you,"
Ebody21 = " - "
Ebody22 = "%" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine






' Begins loop for adherence entry, loops until no further records exist to enter.


'Resets variables for body of the email.
    intbody = ""
    ebody = ""

'Conditional, if agent doesn't have overtime for tomorrow, skips to next agent..


'Continues to reset variables for email communication
    eto = Sheets("Emails").Range("Supname") & ";" & Sheets("Emails").Range("managerName") 'sets the value in email data tab for To field
    ecc = "christopher.meyers@pace.com" 'sets the value in email data tab for CC field
    esub = "Aux 2 Escalation" 'sets the value in email data tab for Subject field
    intbody = Sheets("Emails").Range("d3").Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
  ebody = Ebody12 + intbody12 + ebody15 + ebody11 + Ebody10 + Ebody13 + ebody + ebody1 + intbody3 + inbody + Ebody21 + intbody4 + ebody2 + ebody3 + intbody + ebody7 + intbody5 + ebody4 + intbody2 + Ebody22 + ebody6 + ebody20

'Starts outlook application to send email.
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

'Sets variables for email.
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .To = eto
            .CC = ecc
            .BCC = ebcc
            .Subject = esub
            .Body = ebody
            .Importance = 2
            'You can add other files also like this
            '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
            .Display 'or use .Send
        End With

' Unlocks outlook
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing



' Removes the row and loops back to the beginning to enter a new record.


Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")


Rows(6).EntireRow.Delete


End Sub
```

These two are the ones that I am wanting to show up [H]:MM:SS format

```
intbody5 = Sheets("Emails").Range("Auxhours").Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine


intbody = Sheets("Emails").Range("stafftime") & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
```

I've tried

```
tempfile = Sheets("Emails").Range("stafftime") & Format (Time, "[H]:MM:SS")
```

and using the tempfile instead of the intbody in the body portion of the coding but it just retunrs the same numbers with 00:00:00 at the end.

Any Help wwould be appreicated

Comment: did you try .text instead of .value?.....also for the body of an email you can code it in html which might be a little easier when your working with multiple lines

intbody5 = Sheets("Emails").Range("Auxhours").text& vbNewLine & vbNewLine

Comment: OMG THANKS YOU. Been beating my head for an hour. the .text worked

Comment: NP .text puts it as you view it in the cell glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

Use .text instead of .value

.text puts it as you view it in the cell

```
intbody5 = Sheets("Emails").Range("Auxhours").text & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
```